# Creating bordering polygons from spatial point data for plotting in leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet, gis, geospatial, polygon

Hello (mapping novice here!)

I have had a good hunt around and can't find a solution to what seems to be a tricky problem.

I have basic XY (coordinate) data:

[image: location / land polygons (shapefile)]

What I want to do is create neighbouring polygons based on the coordinate data that do not overlap and have a certain size limit (so they don't extend forever into the ocean).

Forgive my poor MS Paint skills, but the desired outcome would be something like this:

[image]

I have a polygon that marks the land/sea interface so polygons cannot overlap that either.

I am using Leaflet to make these maps interactive, its not for any statistical analysis but to provide an overview.

The ultimate aim is to have each polygon coloured by a variable (e.g. Temperature) with ecological data overlaid.

Some example data:

```
    > data[1:10,]
   Station  Lat_dec  Long_dec Surface_T
1      247 50.33445 -2.240283     15.19
2      245 50.58483 -2.535217     14.11
3      239 50.16883 -2.509250     15.41
4      225 50.32848 -2.765967     15.34
5      229 50.63900 -2.964800     14.09
6      227 50.33757 -3.303217     15.12
7      217 50.16657 -3.563817     15.13
8      207 49.66683 -3.556550     15.04
9      213 50.16512 -3.824667     14.97
10     219 49.83707 -3.815483     14.78
```

the Code to produce figure 1 is a basic leaflet script:

```
leaflet() %>% 
  addProviderTiles('Esri.OceanBasemap'
  ) %>% 
  addCircleMarkers(data = data,
                   lng = ~Long_dec,
                   lat = ~Lat_dec,
                   radius = 2
  ) %>%
  addPolygons(data = Land,
              weight = 1,
              color = 'black')
```

Its been frustrating me all day, most of the examples use downloaded polygons (e.g. what seems to be the classic US States rather than making them)

Any help greatly appreciated! (or am I asking too much!)

Jim

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is something to get started with:

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

#create sf object with points
stations <- st_as_sf( df, coords = c( "Long_dec", "Lat_dec" ) ) 

#create voronoi/thiessen polygons
v <- stations %>% 
  st_union() %>%
  st_voronoi() %>%
  st_collection_extract()

library(leaflet)
leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  addCircleMarkers( data = stations ) %>%
  addPolygons( data = v )
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant thanks for the contribution, I'll read into those functions!

Comment: Just a thought, to make things easy, is there a way to clip v to another polygon, for ease

Comment: @Jim take a look at the bottom of this vignette from the `sf`-package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sf/vignettes/sf3.html

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks for your help! R is awesome.

Comment: Hi @Wimpel, I am still struggling to find an elegant solution but its got me truly stumped, I wondered if you had any further insight?

Comment: @Jim hard to say, as I don't know your exact problem. Perhaps it's better to ask a new question here on SO. This one is about creating the polygons around the stations, which has bene done using the voronoi-function..

Comment: This guide works, maybe you are familiar with it?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52475357/error-when-clipping-sf-voronoi-polygons-to-boundary-box

Comment: @Wimpel, your solution is still useful down the line, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The above answer helped me a bit, but I found my solution here: https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/474 and thought I would share the example I was working on in case it helps anyone else and also uses real data which might be of interest.

```
## reshape used for colsplit function only
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
library(sf)

##define coordinate systems (rdnew is for Netherlands, but works for Denmark also)
latlong = "+init=epsg:4326"
rdnew = "+init=epsg:28992"
```

These vectors create a data frame of solar thermal district heating sites which were derived from solarheatdata.eu, but ultimately had to be manually found on Google Earth

```
## create vector of names
site_names <- c("Strandby","Taars","Vraa","Jerslev", "Saeby", "Saeby 2","Jetsmark","Aabybro","Hjallerup", 
                "Dronninglund","Asaa","Ulsted", "Mou", "Snedsted", "Durup","Hadsund","Gjerlev","Ramsing-Lem-Lihme", "Haderup",
                "Feldborg","Frederiks","Karup" ,"Silkeborg", "Rye","Braedstrup 2","Braedstrup","Ejstrupholm", 
                "Torring" , "Torring2","Vildbjerg","Ornhoj-Gronbjerg", "Tim", "Ringkjobing", "Egtved" ,"Hejnsvig", 
                "Skovlund", "Tistrup" ,"Sig" , "Oksbol" , "Gording", "Holsted" , "Christiansfeld", "Gram" ,"Vojens",
                "Toftlund","Logumkloster", "Grasten" ,"Broager", "St. Rise","Aeroskobing","Marstel","Sydlangeland",
                "Tommerup","Ringe", "Lolland","Oster", "Sydfalster","Refa-Gedser","Stege", "Sandved-Tornemark", "Fuglebjerg", 
                "Haslev" ,"Hvidebaek", "Svebolle","Smorum", "Skuldelev","Jaegerspris","Nykobings", "Hundested", "Vejby", 
                "Helsinge")

## Vector of IDs

site_ids <- c("4", "79","45","51","14","115","49","110","81","37","40","3","32","47","114","54","53","112","44","24","30", 
"31", "100", "43", "99", "1", "16",  "5",  "86", "42", "25", "27", "11", "76", "12", "23", "15", "34", "13", "19",  "98",  "28", 
"6", "18", "36","50", "22", "10", "39", "8", "2",  "33", "82","116", "97", "93","17", "102", "83", "94", "96","103", "35",
"29", "104", "48", "9",  "41",  "46","21", "20") 

## site coordinates
site_latlons <- c("57.488519, 10.486884", "57.392246, 10.120313","57.361012, 9.947647",  "57.284072, 10.096013", "57.317312, 10.502039",
                  "57.315924, 10.501388", "57.204279, 9.670758",  "57.146419, 9.762861",  "57.175564, 10.151121", "57.162937, 10.253277",
                  "57.155180, 10.394182", "57.078654, 10.252327", "56.962971, 10.214036", "56.888538, 8.538094",  "56.741672, 8.963102",
                  "56.736111, 10.112385", "56.591002, 10.136062", "56.591399, 8.791363", "56.392732, 8.990445",  "56.336781, 8.940749",
                  "56.337432, 9.245461",  "56.311003, 9.163035",  "56.208234, 9.546451",  "56.069370, 9.692441", "55.977873, 9.623761",
                  "55.978695, 9.629253",  "55.980475, 9.293377",  "55.855816, 9.492632",  "55.854990, 9.496065",  "56.206777, 8.773864",
                  "56.204275, 8.573454",  "56.190090, 8.312271",  "56.094087, 8.284403",  "55.620152, 9.323732",  "55.695530, 9.007244",
                  "55.742032, 8.702813", "55.717618, 8.613441",  "55.667168, 8.565599",  "55.619889, 8.288348",  "55.476738, 8.803819",
                  "55.506467, 8.903544",  "55.368032, 9.488627", "55.276828, 9.049574",  "55.241101, 9.285634",  "55.199975, 9.080764",
                  "55.051287, 8.960624",  "54.932625, 9.604330",  "54.884324, 9.676783", "54.852033, 10.408747", "54.883866, 10.415010",
                  "54.852505, 10.506659", "54.798816, 10.710182", "55.329109, 10.199913", "55.252603, 10.496850", "54.825794, 11.171034",
                  "54.758955, 11.818087", "54.718146, 11.923282", "54.577268, 11.935755", "55.000648, 12.291542", "55.254072, 11.522817",
                  "55.298998, 11.535034", "55.333998, 11.970144", "55.613226, 11.209546", "55.654732, 11.292038", "55.729510, 12.307020",
                  "55.775250, 12.016991", "55.829130, 12.000715", "55.917183, 11.651009", "55.963456, 11.880701", "56.069852, 12.152346",
                  "56.009482, 12.205189")

##combine and create spatial data frame
sites_sf <- data.frame(site = site_names, id = site_ids, latlon = site_latlons) %>% 
  mutate(colsplit(latlon, ",", c("lon", "lat"))) %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lat", "lon"), crs = 4326) %>% 
  st_transform(28992) %>% 
  dplyr::select(-latlon)
```

The packages rnaturalearth and rnatural earthdata make it easy to import shape files of countries around the world. High resolution can be downloaded but requires rnaturalearthhires to be installed which often fails first time, so 'Medium' has been chosen here.

```
## shapefile of Denmark
library(rnaturalearth)

## download medium scale sf polygon of denmark. 
dk <- ne_countries(country = 'denmark', scale = 'medium', returnclass = 'sf')

## convert to a metres crs
dk_rd <- dk %>% 
  st_transform(28992) %>% 
  st_buffer(5000) ## as the shapefile is not that high resolution some edges are missed off. Buffer is used to cover more coastline, but is not essential.
```

Create the Voroni plot

```
## combine sites
d <- st_union(sites_sf)
## create voroni
v <- st_voronoi(d)

## trim the plot to the country shapefile
p1 <- st_as_sf(st_intersection(st_cast(v), dk_rd), crs = 28992)

## tell R that the geometry is polygons
p1 <- st_cast(p1, "MULTIPOLYGON")

plot(p1)
plot(sites_sf, add = TRUE)



## see on a map
library(mapview)

mapview(p1)+sites_sf
```

[image: mapview plot]

Comment: I am glad you found the question useful! feel free to stick it an upvote!